# SQL QUERY NOT IN

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(accessed_time) AS total
FROM   user_db 
WHERE  application_id LIKE '1%' 
AND accessed_time BETWEEN '" + date1 +"' AND '"+daten+"'
```

This query will fetch all the application id that begin with 1...i need to exclude 101....from result...how can i modify the query

Comment: How far out does the application_id go? I.e., the application_id be of any size but have 1 as the first digit and be excluded? Should 100000000 be excluded but not 200000? Is application_id in fact an integer (some table schema would help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `AND`.

```
SELECT COUNT(accessed_time) AS total
FROM user_db
WHERE application_id LIKE '1%'
  AND application_id <> 101
  AND accessed_time BETWEEN '" + date1 +"' AND '"+daten+"'
```

Comment: Note: Using `LIKE` on numbers is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(accessed_time) AS total 
FROM user_db 
WHERE application_id LIKE '1%' AND accessed_time BETWEEN '" + date1 +"' AND '"+daten+"' 
AND application_id <> '101'
```

Comment: looks like you're new to SO, so maybe you don't know: please don't post an answer, if exactly the same solution is already posted (take a look at The Scrum Meisters answer) / please try to explain _why_ this is the solution, don't just post the code / please use code-formatting (mark the code an press the "{}"-symbol in the text-editors toolbar)(for this time, i'll fix that for you)